# Sublime text 3 - coloring file extensions in sidebar tree

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I color file names based off of their file extensions? 
The picture below is in brackets.io and compared to the tree in sublime there is no color to highlight the file type

Brackets tree

[image]

Sublime tree

[image]

Comment: You can't. Sublime doesn't provide the GUI functionality for something to modify whole or partial filenames to a different color at the current time. So it's not possible to make different files different colors, you can't make a file a different color if is in source control with changes pending, etc.

Comment: Most people have the ability to discriminate a full stop (period) and read the suffix that follows. You don't need to syntax highlight *everything*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SublimeText - Highlight/Fade file names from sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408789/sublimetext-highlight-fade-file-names-from-sidebar)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Sublime file icons](https://github.com/ihodev/sublime-file-icons) package to **add icons** based on the file extension instead ?

here is a tree from in my Sublime Text 3 for a Jekyll project:

[image]