# SublimeText - Highlight/Fade file names from sidebar

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, atom-editor

Is there a way I can fade file names (not hide them) from the sidebar based on .gitignore and highlight file names if they've been modified or changed?

Something like Atom git integration:
[image]

If the package doesn't already exist, would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on building it myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443299/sublime-text-3-coloring-file-extensions-in-sidebar-tree#comment70097617_41443299

Comment: "Sublime doesn't provide the GUI functionality for something to modify whole or partial filenames to a different color at the current time."

Says it all I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ST currently doesn't offer the functionality to style the filenames in the sidebar, you will need to wait for this feature to be implemented in a future version/build of ST:
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/867